# Keith Wood's Jquery SVG Plugin: Transform without animation?

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-animate, transform, jquery-svg

Using Keith Wood's SVG Jquery plugin, is there any way to move/scale/rotate a path without using the animate function? I want an instant change, and I'm guessing the animate function has unnecessary overheads.

What I'm actually doing is creating a path, cloning it, then rotating/moving it, and repeat. (For example, drawing multiple tick marks for a clock).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer was staring me in the face under the animate section of the documentation:

```
var myrect = svg.rect(25, 25, 150, '25%', 10, 10, 
    {
        fill: 'none', stroke: 'blue', strokeWidth: 3, 
        transform: 'rotate(0, 100, 75)'
    }
);
```